# React-Native: Passing data through a FlatList Selection

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im currently trying to pass information through an arrow function that gets called when a user selects a row within the flat list. However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the data to the next screen appropriately.

My current implementation can be seen below:

```
import ...

class ViewFollowingScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      allUsers: [],
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
    }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {...};

  searchUsers(searchBarText) {...};

  _onPressItem = () => { 
    /**
    HOW DO YOU PASS THE INFORMATION OF THE SELECTED USER TO THE ViewUser SCREEN??
    **/
     this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewUser')//Needs to include user information
  };

  componentDidMount() {...};

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {...};

  renderSeparator = () => {...};

  renderHeader = () => {...};

  renderFooter = () => {...};

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressItem}>
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={`${item.name.first[0].toUpperCase() + item.name.first.substr(1,item.name.first.length)} ${item.name.last[0].toUpperCase() + item.name.last.substr(1,item.name.last.length)}`}
        subtitle={'Followers: 15' }
        avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
        containerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <List containerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 0}}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.email}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          />
        </List>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ViewFollowingScreen;
```

I am currently able to navigate to the next screen when a user selects a row in the flatlist, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to pass the appropriate data between the two.

Please let me know if you need any additional info.. I'd be happy to edit my question accordingly

Any help is **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the user information through the params when you are navigating to the next screen. Inside your onPressItem function edit as below:

```
  _onPressItem = () => { 
     this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewUser',{
         user: user // your user details
     })
  };
```

and then you can get the user detail on the next screen by

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.user
```

**Edit:**

change the `_renderItem` function to this:

```
  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this._onPressItem(item)}}>
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={`${item.name.first[0].toUpperCase() + item.name.first.substr(1,item.name.first.length)} ${item.name.last[0].toUpperCase() + item.name.last.substr(1,item.name.last.length)}`}
        subtitle={'Followers: 15' }
        avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
        containerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
```

and `onPressItem`:

```
  _onPressItem = (user) => { 
     this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewUser',{
         user: user   //your user details
     })
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, my only question is how do I get the information from the selected user to the _onPressItem function? How do I know which user was selected?

Comment: Inside your _renderItem function you get the item and you can send this item to your onPressItem function so you will get the selected user. You can check the edited answer for detail :)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this is exactly what I was looking for